# Как испраавить баг с исчезновением иконок в вёрстке?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Всем привет, надеюсь кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным. Сделал вёрстку небольшого лендинга, у меня всё отлично выглядит как по макету, скидываю заказчице, а она говорит что у неё иконок нет, я сначала начал думал что может где кеш не почистила, и прочее, но все мои догадки были безрезультатны. Спросил в группе у парней может кто-нибдуь знает в чём дело, подсказали что может быть из-за бутстрапа, подключил новую версию бутстрапа но нет никаких результатор, всё как прежде.
[image: Вот как у меня выглядит]
[image: Вот как выглядит у другого человека, и вчастности у заказчицы]
Что с этим делать я не знаю, может есть предположения как это можно пофиксить.
[Ссылка на сайт](http://juliayas.beget.tech/)

Comment: всё показывает, может у неё не подключился font-awesome

Comment: Там я использую 2 типа иконок, а неё они ни в шапке ни в футере не подгружаются. В шапке Font-Awesome в футере обычные png

Comment: Судя по скринам - проблема в safari. Гляньте тут - вдруг поможет https://qna.habr.com/q/526083

Comment: Скрины только для примеры, такое поведение проявляется и в Safari и Google Chrome, Firefox

Comment: Да, странное поведение - только что проверил на ios и android - иконки отображаются